# Where should I call socket.on in react?

Tags: reactjs, websocket, react-redux

Currently I m using socket.on in constructor. But I cannot use setState there. So which life cycle should I use to call socket.on ?

```
socket.on('users', function (user) {
            switch (user.meta.action) {
                case 'create':
                    store.dispatch(appendUser(user.data));
                    break;

                case 'update':
                    store.dispatch(replaceUser(user.data));
                    break;

                case 'delete':
                    store.dispatch(deleteUser());
                    break;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the Websockets connection to be established when you initialize the React component, you should do it in the `componentDidMount`. This way you will be able to use `setState`.